# REGEX get all content after a series of special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this regular expression to correctly get values for `id` and `description`

`\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&amp;description=(\w+))?\$\$`

Example here:
https://regex101.com/r/GZVlKf/1

I would ned modify this regex and get any text after the last `$$`.
I tried something like `|?<=/$/$).*$` but with no success.
Could you please point me in the right direction?

Test data:

```
$$id=uniq_id&description=some_description$$ Any text after
$$id=uniq_id$$ Any text after

$$id=uniq_id&description=some_description$$ Any text after

$$id=uniq_id$$ Any text after

Any text after

$$id=uniq_id&description=some_description$$ Any text after $$ dfjhdjfjkhjj $$


<input disabled="" type="checkbox"> Whatever
<input checked="" disabled="" type="checkbox"> Whatever
<input disabled="" type="checkbox"> $$id=uniq_id&amp;description=some_description$$ AX Whatever
<input checked="" disabled="" type="checkbox"> $$id=uniq_id$$ AX Whatever

<input disabled="" type="checkbox"> $$id=uniq_id&amp;description=some_description$$ AX Whatever
```

Comment: Try `\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&amp;description=(\w+))?\$\$(?:(?:(?!\$\$)[\s\S])*$)?`, see https://regex101.com/r/8byeXy/1

Comment: Note it may be enhanced, I just suggested the above to make sure I understand what you actually need to get as output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried you regex, but I cannot get the 3 group with the content after the last $$, could you please have a look? Thanks!

'<input disabled="" type="checkbox"> $$id=uniq_id&amp;description=some_description$$ AX Whatever'.match(/\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&amp;description=(\w+))?\$\$(?:(?:(?!\$\$)[\s\S])*$)?/)

Comment: Just wrap it with a capturing group - https://regex101.com/r/8byeXy/2, or turn the last one into capturing  - https://regex101.com/r/8byeXy/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&amp;description=(\w+))?\$\$([^$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^$]*)*$)?/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Heml27/1).

I added `([^$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^$]*)*$)?` at the end of the pattern that is an optional capturing group matching

- `[^$]*` - zero or more chars other than `$`
- `(?:\$(?!\$)[^$]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\$(?!\$)` - a `$` not followed with another `$`
  - `[^$]*` - zero or more chars other than `$`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correctly understood your question, but if so then you can add `.*` at the end. I think you want something like this:

```
\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&amp;description=(\w+))?\$\$(.*)
                          Here-------------^^^^
```

This will capture the full line after the $$ until `\n` is found.

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZVlKf/2)**

If you want to capture multiple lines, then you could use:

```
\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&amp;description=(\w+))?\$\$([^$]*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZVlKf/3)**

Note: that this approach won't match if you have literal `$` in your text after then last $$. In case you want to also capture `$` then you can use Viktor's comment.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&description=(\w+))?(?:.*)\$\$(.*)
```

> Explanation

- `\$\$id=` - Matches `$$id=`.
- `(\w+)`= Capturing group. Matches one or more character.
- `(?:&description=(\w+))?` - Matches `description=` followed by one or more character(capture group). (? makes it optional).
- `(?:.*)` Non capturing group. Matches anything zero or more time except newline.(Greedy mode)
- `\$\$` - Matches the last `$$`.
- `(.*)` Matches anything except newline zero or time.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZVlKf/4)